# What arguments can I pass to NewForm.aspx using SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options)?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I'd like to create a task with a pre-filled title, as well as set some other properties.  I found this documentation that says I can pass arguments when i call

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410058.aspx

This is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var modalDialog;
    function ShowActionItemDialog(title, questionId) {
        var options = {
            url: '/Lists/Tasks/NewForm.aspx',
            title: questionId + ': ' + title,
            questionId: questionId,
            allowMaximize: false,
            showClose: false,
            width: 800,
            args: {
                title: title,
                questionId: questionId
            },
            height: 600
        };
        modalDialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    };
</script>
```

I have not been able to find any documentation for what args are supported.  I would accept either an answer showing me how to find this information, or providing a better alternative for passing this information to the dialog.  I need to invoke the dialog when a radio button is clicked, so I believe I need to do this with javascript.

Thank you!

**Edit:  The code from the link in the accepted answer works, but you'll need to make sure the client OM js is completely loaded**

I added this code to NewForm.aspx in Sharepoint Designer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(procAuditArgs, "sp.js");

function procAuditArgs(){
    var args = SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog().get_args();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This link might help you out:

http://www.chaholl.com/archive/2010/11/17/using-the-dialog-framework-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

So according to this, you will have to do:

```
var args = SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog().get_args();
```

on the `NewForm.aspx` page to access the values passed on that page.

Comment: Thanks!  I edited my NewForm.aspx in SharePoint Designer.  This part wasn't in the link, but I had to add some code to wait for the Client OM to fully load: See edit to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

I believe SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog().get_args() works within the page opened in dialog only when this page is SharePoint-based, i.e. the page includes the all necessary SP js-files. So, I prefer using window.frameElement.dialogArgs to get access to the passed parameters. It works on whatever page you open in dialog. Some additional details are in my brief blog post here - [How to pass parameters into a Modal Dialog Window and then access them](http://dotnetfollower.com/wordpress/2012/08/sharepoint-how-to-access-the-parameters-passed-into-a-modal-dialog-window/).

Comment: A word of notice from the moderator :-) When you include links to your own blog in your answers, please remembe to mention that it is your blog so that there is no confusion. Also read the [faq] especially about declaration and self promotion. Fix this and you are all good, thanx ;)